How is "why should" different from "why do"?
Does this "should" have some special meaning?

For young professionals, why should they want to work in a large commercial bank?

What difference is there from just using "do"?

For young professionals, why do they want to work in a large commercial bank?


OED gives the meaning of should for this particular structure:

II.iii.23.a.
In questions introduced by why (or equivalent word), implying the speaker's inability to conceive any reason or justification for something actual or contemplated, or any ground for believing something to be fact.

OED mentions that this usage appeared in "Old English". The latest example it provides is from 1890:

‘I do hope she will not be dull’, said Evelyn... ‘Why should she be dull?’
(‘L. Falconer’, Mademoiselle Ixe i)

Cambridge says:

used after "why" when giving or asking the reason for something:

Why should anyone want to eat something so horrible?


Though the element of surprise and disbelief is missing in Cambridge's definition, it is present in your first example, as Longman notes:

used to express surprise that something has happened or that someone has asked you a particular question

Why should anyone want to marry Tony? (Longman)


If you replace should by do, the question becomes more neutral, as asking for the mere reason why something happens. This usage is called putative should. In his book, Essentials of English Grammar (1933), Otto Jespersen calls it emotional should:

We may use the term emotional should for the use of should in passing a judgment of an emotional character (agreeable or disagreeable surprise, indignation, joy) on some occurrence which may, or may not, be a fact.
A sentence like

Why was the date omitted?

is a mere factual question, but

Why should the date of the document be omitted?

implies wonder and, possibly, some suspicion of the purity of the motives.


Isn't your answer on 'putative should' near definitive?

Forgotten completely about that answer. Never mind, here new information was added, so it's all right even if the question gets closed. I think this question is more detailed by asking particular structure of why with should.

It's best to augment previous answers with new information, perhaps pointing out different analyses or terminology. ELU is intended to be an easily searchable, well-collated resource rather than a plum pudding (after Thomson's model of the atom).

I think it would be weird to go to my former answer and add information about the interrogative use of "should" which that OP does not ask about...

Questions are seen as springboards for detailed coverage of closely related issues; ELU is not in the first instance merely a Q and A site. It would be weird for CGEL say to cover 'emotional should' in depth on pages 456 and 1745.

[implies wondering, not wonder :)]

"Though the element of surprise and disbelief is missing in Cambridge's definition, it is present" -- sometimes.  Sometimes not.  Consider "Why should drivers stop at red lights?"  or "Why should students get a good night's sleep before sitting for an exam?" Those are simple queries for a reason, no surprise or disbelief present.  They may or may not be rhetorical.

@JohnBollinger Yes, you are right. I meant that it is present in the OP's example.

"It's best to augment previous answers with new information, perhaps pointing out different analyses or terminology" Translated: you should not post a new answer if you can add further detail in an old answer.  Me: Why should they? The questions are not identical.

ELU is intended to be an easily searchable, well-collated resource rather than a plum pudding (after Thomson's model of the atom). Translated: Answers should be as detailed as possible and be self-contained. A visitor should not have to look for a plum in a plum pudding... I'm making that last one up. No idea what's he on about. I now have to google "plum pudding" (which I know is a dessert but how that is connected to the atom is perhaps not relevant on an English Language Q &A site) Perhaps comments should be self-contained too, including references and links...

Thomson held that atoms are uniform spheres of positively charged matter in which electrons are embedded. Popularly known as the plum pudding model, it had to be abandoned (1911) on both theoretical and experimental grounds in favour of the Rutherford atomic model, in which the electrons describe orbits about a tiny positive nucleus. The analogy is still mysterious. No doubt someone will explain.

Your excerpt does not provide enough context to say which should be used, but there are differences between the two statements.
Why should, asks what you think are aspects or POTENTIAL aspects of the career that would cause a young professional to desire it.  If this was a conversation as to how to increase the number of people in the field the answer could include aspects that do not currently exist. While the aspect could exist in potential, it would have to be real.  Frex, they shouldn’t desire it because it makes them immortal, because it doesn’t. Free health care for life doesn’t exit either, but could be added.
Why do, asks what aspects or perceived aspects of the career currently cause young professionals to enter the field. Note that in this case, perception does not have to match reality.  Young professionals may desire the job with the expectations that it will make them immortal, it won’t but that is irrelevant to their motivations.  It makes them wrong, it doesn’t mean that isn’t what motivates them.
Obviously there is a great deal of overlap between the two, and the speaker may even be using the wrong version, or both may be acceptable. We can’t know without greater context.

In an answer posted as a comment, Andreas Blass wrote:

The version with "do" presupposes that they actually want  to work in a large commercial bank. It asks why that is the case. The version with "should" has no such presupposition; it would be a reasonable response to a question like "Why do none of them work for large commercial banks?"


The key difference in meaning here is that in one case:

For young professionals, why should they want to work in a large commercial bank?

We're saying that they currently don't want to work there. In other words, I'm saying that young professionals don't want to work there, so please tell me why you think they should actually want this?
Note: others have said that this doesn't explicitly imply that young professionals don't want to work there. However, in everyday conversation that is what will be generally inferred.
But in the other case:

For young professionals, why do they want to work in a large commercial bank?

We're saying that they currently do want to work there. In other words, I'm saying that young professionals already want to work there, and I'm simply asking you why you think that is the case.

In both cases, we're asking what the reasons would be for wanting to work in a large commercial bank, but depending on should/do we're either implying that this is currently the case or not.

Modal should often expresses that something is advisable or prudent or, if that meaning is diluted somewhat, well worth considering. Modals tend to express a range of meanings in that way. Those meanings are pretty much the "core" of should (not a "special" meaning). So I would paraphrase the question as follows:

What does a large commercial bank have to offer young professionals that  make it a choice well worth considering?

Inasmuch as the sentence opens with "For young professionals", we don't need to introduce the element of surprise. Indeed, I find such a spin somewhat incongruous:  Why would a young professional ever want to work in a large commercial bank? Although a young musician or arty person might not want to work in such an environment, it seems a natural choice for a "young professional", something they would be prudent to consider at the very least.
If this were the question, I'd concur about an element of the unexpected, that Why should...? suggests there would be some resistance to the idea:

For young liberal arts majors, why should they want to work in a large commercial bank?

NOTE:In live speech, should would receive rising emphasis if someone were rejecting the notion actually, or only rhetorically, and it would appear in italics in text.
Why do ...? on the other hand is just asking for the reasons young professionals find large commercial banks a good place to work.
